# Blur text in TextField

Tags: flutter, textfield, blur

Is there an easy way to blur a text field? The usual blur effect on containers has unwanted side effects when used in combination with elevation.

And this does not work at all:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Container(
      child: Text("Text to hide")
    ),
    BackdropFilter(
      filter: ImageFilter.blur(
        sigmaX: 5,
        sigmaY: 5,
      ),
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.8),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you find a way to blur exactly like the picture you illustrate? Thank you

Comment: @Anah Yes, with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `Paint` for the `foreground` of the `TextStyle`:

```
Text(
          'text to hide',
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 36,
              foreground: Paint()
                ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
                ..color = Colors.grey
                ..maskFilter = MaskFilter.blur(BlurStyle.normal, 6)),
        ),
```

Result:

[image: res]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                    child: Text("Text to hide")
                ),
                BackdropFilter(
                  filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                    sigmaX: 2,
                    sigmaY: 2,
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    height: 25,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your example. It seems that this does not work properly in a complete UI because of the way the backdropfilter works. Or I was just not able to use it correctly.